# How do I make a multi-threaded app use all the cores on Ubuntu under VMWare?

Tags: c++, high-performance

I have a multi-threaded C++ app (using pThreads) that processes a massive flat file that works great on Windows - uses all four cores on my puny CPU. Client wants to run the same code on Red Hat on a fire-breathing 64 Xeon CPU machine. So I compile it here (g++), ran it on Ubuntu on VMWare, and code only used one of the four cores. So I'm thinking that is a VMWare problem, and I send code to client - where it does the same thing (as far as I can tell remotely - mpstat -P ALL shows the CPUs barely loaded). Do I need to do something to force Red Hat to spread out the threads? Is there something I'm missing - I'm trying to get the "nice" priority changed next - but I feel like I'm missing something.

I can post code - but like I said, works great on Windows, uses pThreads, etc.

Comment: [Get/Set CPU affinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity)

Comment: If `mpstat` shows that all CPUs are "barely loaded", then it seems that your program is not doing anything at all, not even on one CPU.  Maybe you have a bottleneck in the I/O code? (Look for high values in the "%iowait" column in mpstat output.)  Does the application behavior and the system load change if you increase/decrease the number of threads in your application?

Comment: Is the xeon also running VMware? is it a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to diagnose if this is a problem with your VM environment or your code. Here are some things to consider about your VM.

- Do you have vmware configured to allow access to multiple CPU's? I don't have experience with recent versions, but it used to be something you had to specifically allow. In VirtualBox, I have an option in the virtual machine configuration that states how many CPU's the guest is allowed to work with.
- If you `cat /proc/cpuinfo` from your Ubuntu guest do you see more than one CPU?
- Do you get proper use of multiple CPU's if you do something generic like going into your kernel source an running a kernel compile with `make -j10`?

If any of these things turn up wrong, they would indicate your VM is misconfigured rather than there being a problem with your code.